# no repeat calling Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I make my function not to repeat the multiple calls, if multiple calls were made in mins?

```
var s = 1; 
function foo(x) {
  if (s === 1) {
    console.log('done');
    setTimeout(function(){
      s =1; 
    }, 10000);
  } else {
    s = 2; 
    console.log('no more repeat calling');

  }
}

foo(1); 
foo(2);
```

I am expecting the result -

```
done 
no more repeat calling
```

Comment: check on x not on s

Comment: [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Answer (score 3):

Because `s` is never being set to `2`.  It looks like you meant to do that in the *if* block, rather than the *else* block:

```
if (s === 1) {
    console.log('done');
    s = 2;  // <--- here
    setTimeout(function(){
        s = 1; 
    }, 10000);
} else {
    console.log('no more repeat calling');
}
```

That way the first call will update the `s` flag, so subsequent calls will go to the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var s = 1; 
function foo(x) {
    if (s === 1) {
        s = 0; 
        console.log('done');
        setTimeout(function(){
            s = 1; 
        }, 10000);
    } else {
        console.log('no more repeat calling');
    } 
}
foo(1); foo(2);foo(3);
```

Comment: It will be better, if we explain our answer. Not just a code block. Right ?